Cox regression assumptions
I am analyzing the association between a plasma biomarker and disease incidence, self-reported via yearly questionnaires. The total sample size is 824 of which 65 reported at least one event (I am not considering multiple events). Apart from event occurrence, all other variables are measured at baseline. I would use Cox proportional hazard regression models, but I am not familiar with this model and am quite confused about the assumption plots I obtained.
My fully adjusted model looks like this:
assumpt.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ contvar1 +  
                           contvar2 + catvar1 + catvar2 +                   
                           catvar3 + contvar3 + catvar4 + contvar4 + contvar5, data = data_assumpt.cox)

were contvars are continuous variables and catvars and categorical variables. My main exposure of interest in contvar1.
I checked the PH assumption, which did not suggest violation (p>0.05 for all variables and global).
For the influential points, I checked the deviance and noticed that all participants who reported an event are clustered at the top of the graph, while those who didn't are at the bottom. Also, the average deviance is not 0. But it's not clear to me what I should do about it.
ggcoxdiagnostics(assumpt.cox, type = "deviance",
             linear.predictions = FALSE, ggtheme = theme_bw()) 


For linearity, I found two main ways to check this assumption.

With an empty model:

    ggcoxfunctional(Surv(time, event) ~ contvar1 + I(contvar1)^2 + log(contvar1) + 
                  sqrt(contvar1), data = data_assumpt.cox)



With a fully adjusted model:

data_assumpt.cox %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=contvar1, y=residuals(assumpt.cox, type="martingale"))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="blue") +
  geom_smooth(color="red") +
  theme_bw()



I've understood that in the first set of plots, I should see a good correlation between the data points and the residual line, while in the second the red line should be (mostly) straight at 0. But overall they should tell me the same thing. Is it correct or one is to be preferred over the other?
From these plots, I would conclude that the linearity assumption is violated.
But if so, what can I do about it, since the transformations don't seem to help? I also tried to exclude the two extreme values in contvar1 (one with and one without the event), but it improved only slightly.
Sorry for the long post, I hope it is at least clear.
Thanks a lot!

Welcome to the site. I'm assuming, since you have results that you have time to biomarker detection, or some other time-to-event variable along with the actual event. It's not clear in your question, however. Also, is it days? minutes? hours? weeks? months?

Thanks! Yes, the time variable indicates the time (in years) between baseline (when the biomarker was measured and all other variables were assessed) and the follow-up year when the event occurrence was assessed.

Sounds good. Just a note, your deviance plot is not alarming. It's the nature of survival data for the plot to look like that. See this answer for more: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/508582/97844

Also this question and answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/498018/97844

Thank you! So, it is not a problem if they are not uniformely distributed around zero. Now it's clear.

Do you have any comment about linearity?

No but EdM knows much more than I do, so follow that advice below and from those links above

First, recognize that you don't have enough events to fit a survival model with so many predictor variables. What matters for survival analysis is the number of events, not the number of observations. A rough rule of thumb is that trying to estimate more than 1 unpenalized coefficient for every 15 events puts you at risk of overfitting. That means no more than 4 or 5 coefficients in your case (65 events). See Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies, particularly Chapter 4, for those limits and for strategies to deal with them.
Second, the most important residuals to evaluate in a Cox model are the scaled Schoenfeld residuals, which document adherence to the proportional hazards (PH) assumption. Don't simply rely on p>0.05 in a PH test. You need to examine the magnitude and nature of PH deviations, as a "statistically insignificant" violation of PH on that arbitrary basis might still be of substantial practical importance. Look at the plots of residuals over time. For that I'd recommend that you don't use the survminer package, as its default settings can be misleading. Don't worry if there is a sign of PH violation; you can still learn a lot from a Cox model when PH is violated.
Third, deviance residuals might be useful for identifying outliers, but they otherwise are disappointing in practice. As they are defined to have a mean value of 0, I wonder whether your plot from the survminer package is cutting off the top of the display of deviance residuals, as it seems to be for the 2x2 matrix of plots in your first evaluation of linearity via martingale residuals.
Fourth, although it's possible to use martingale residuals to estimate the form of the association between a continuous predictor and outcome, it's usually simpler to let the data tell you the form directly via a flexible fit with a restricted cubic spline or other generalized additive model. That way you don't have to guess a particular transformation yourself. In any event, note that the shapes of the smoothed curves in your plots seem to be driven by very extreme cases at the highest continuous predictor values.

Thank you for your answer! I will consider removing some less important coefficients. I've seen that there is no statistical difference between the current and two simpler models. But indeed the pattern of Schoenfeld residuls over time is not very linear for two variables, despite the large p. So I think it would be better to exclude these var rather than adding an interaction term (also considering the sample size), do you agree?

As for the deviance residuals, I have looked the values and the plot doesn't seem to be cut, given that there are only two values over 3.5. For the linearity, I've checked with restricted cubic splines and it suggests linearity. There is no difference when I exclude the most extreme values.

@elena1234 omitting an outcome-associated predictor from a Cox model can bias coefficient estimates of included predictors toward 0. See the Harrell reference for ways to combine/eliminate predictors to avoid overfitting. For PH the main problem is an overall trend in Schoenfeld residuals; other nonlinearity can be OK. Even without PH, you still get time-averaged coefficients that you can use with robust standard errors. See this page and its links. Probably best to keep the variables but show and discuss patterns in their Schoenfeld residuals.

The CPH does not assume anything about the residuals. Per the National Institute of Health (and other sources) the three assumptions are:

Proportional hazards. You have tested this.
Independent observations.
Uninformative censoring - i.e. people (or whatever) who have been censored have the same risk as those who have not.

I think (but I am not sure in my uncaffeinated state) that the thing you note about the residuals as odd is a natural consequence of the fact that the model is not perfect.

Thank you for your reply. However, now I am even more confused because everywhere I looked this up the deviance and the linearity assumptions were mentioned. I am going to read the paper you cited.

I have ssen linearity mentioned.
